# Format postgres numeric like money ($0.20)

Tags: postgresql, formatting, currency, to-char

I have a numeric column that I'm trying to format like currency, but I can't seem to get the format right. I currently have:

```
to_char(my_column, 'fml9999999999999999999D9999999999999999999')
```

but it outputs

```
$.2
```

If I remove the 'fm' modifier, it outputs:

```
$                    .2000000000000000000
```

How would I go about getting it to preserve at least 1 digit on the left, and at least 2 digits on the right while removing all the rest of the trailing 0's?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: the trick is to use 0's where you want it to preserve the digits:

```
to_char(my_column, 'fm9999999999999990D00')
```